# How can I start a batch file after logon?

Tags: windows, batch-file, autostart

I'd like to start a batch file when I log on with a specific account. The problem is, that specific account doesn't have the right to copy to the `Startup` folder, or install anything on the machine (Windows 7). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have those rights then you can use Task Scheduler. Open start and start to type "task" and you'll see that program. Open it and click "Create Basic Task". Type the name and a desciption. Click next and choose "When I log on". Click next and choose "Start a program". After that, browse your batch file location and add the arguments if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It works well. :)